# Switch classes jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a load of elements all named .client-dark and .client-light.

I want to switch these classes around and I'm trying it with...

```
 $('.clients-logo .container-fluid .row:nth-child(2)').find('.client-light').addClass('client-dark').removeClass('client-light');
 $('.clients-logo .container-fluid .row:nth-child(2)').find('.client-dark').addClass('client-light').removeClass('client-dark');
```

The first line of the above works but then the 2nd line overwrites it, is it possible to do both of these simultaneously?

Answer (score 5):

You can change both at once with [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). It supports using multiple class names separated by a space:

```
$('.clients-logo .container-fluid .row:nth-child(2)').find('.client-light,.client-dark').toggleClass('client-dark client-light');
```

Just search for both together and toggle both.

And a quick test to show it working: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r59uw7m6/ (just click anywhere in the output pane to toggle).

**Note:** as `@gegillam` also mentions, it is usually a good idea to have a base styling and a single class that changes it to the opposite when toggled.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
$('.clients-logo').toggleClass('dark-mode');
```

the light mode could then be the default, but it wouldn't be explicitly on the item.